# How to place a RelativeLayout at the bottom of a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout`, and this  Layout has two childs, one is a `MapView` and the other a `RelativeLayout` that contains a button.

I want it to look like that

[image]

but my transparent box (a `RelativeLayout`) is always displayed at the top of the map.

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"/>

    <test.project.TransparentPanel 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">   

        <Button 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Click Me!"/>   

    </test.project.TransparentPanel>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(i've left out some things in the code)

Comment: Why is `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` used twice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding a alignParentBottom option to the transparent panel.

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"/>

  <test.project.TransparentPanel
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

      <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Click Me!"/>         

  </test.project.TransparentPanel>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

As Konstantin pointed out use `layout_alignParentBottom` to position the button at the bottom of your view. The problem now is that the mapview will also stretch itself out to the bottom of the parent. Therefore the mapview will ´grow´ under the button until the parent is filled.

Try the following. First position the button at the bottom of the parent view, then align above the button.

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <test.project.TransparentPanel
    android:id="@+id/button_area"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

      <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Click Me!"/>         

  </test.project.TransparentPanel>

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    layout_above="@id/button_area"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```