# Aligning Android Button To Bottom in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, button, alignment

I'm trying to align a button to the bottom right and bottom left of my screen, using a RelativeLayout.  I want to do this to keep the same relative layout across different screen sizes. Currently, the buttons on my screen move up/down depending on the resolution of the screen.  320x480 puts the buttons higher on the screen versus 480x800.  I'm trying to get my screens to look the same between the two sizes.

Comment: You'll have to show us your xml.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a RelativeLayout at the bottom of a RelativeLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492721/how-to-place-a-relativelayout-at-the-bottom-of-a-relativelayout)

Answer (score 56):

I know this is an old thread but it shows up at the top of search results so I figure it can't hurt to confirm that

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

worked for me in RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using android:layout_alignParent* ? That should justify it to a side regardless of screen size.

Where * is Bottom or Top or Left or Right

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.kronplatz"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/locateMeButton"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:src="@drawable/me" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MapCenterButton"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:src="@drawable/fadenkreuz_klein" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MapNextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/androidmarker" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

On addition what AedonEtLIRA said you should make sure that the RelativeLayout you have always filled the whole display area. ie. that you don't have any size defined in any place in the view hierarchy but instead match_parent is used. If you then used the layout definitions given by AedonEtLIRA you should get exactly what you want.